# Read and Write files to package in project on Windows and Mac in Java

Tags: java, windows, macos, file, persistence

I am so sorry if this has been posted before.

What I am trying to do is write and read a simple string to a file located in one of the packages in my project. Inside Source Packages I have a package called "resources". Here i want to read a file called `myfile.txt`, do some stuff with it and save it again as `newmyfile.txt`. Just simple reading and storing of CSV data.

I have created a reader, which looks like this:

```
public BufferedReader getFileReader(String fileNameWithExtension, String sourcePackage) {
        try {
            String file = "/" + sourcePackage + "/" + fileNameWithExtension;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
            return br;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works fine on my Mac. Reading up on this i find out that i have to use File.separator in order to get it to work on all operating systems. So i change this, and still it don´t work. Somewhere it is said that a relative path always starts with `/` regardless of operating system when using relative paths, and other places `../`. As a complete newbie on file storage on Java, I am confused.

There is also a lot of ways to read and write files, and I don´t know what method to choose, and why.

What is the best way for me to read and create files where all I want to do is save one long string, or an array of strings?

Comment: Using forward slashes on windows from Java works fine. Things become more complicated when you need things like the drive letter as well...

Comment: If you are working with Eclipse or  other IDEs.you are doing something wrong with file location.

Comment: *"i find out that i have to use File.separator"*  No!!  Not when using `getResource(String)`.  It ***always*** takes forward slash.

Comment: you mean he can't use File.separator,because it will work with getResource(String) but not with getResourceAsStream(String).Am I right?If I am wrong correct me Please.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  yes thank you.I read something.I got it.

Comment: @AkaIDIOT: I do not need the drive letter, only the path to a file relative to the source folder of my project.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I am using Java packages to separate between logic, models and resources. Inside these, I have regular .java class files, not jars. This is a simple project where I only use packages to better group class files.

Comment: @Sunleo: I am using NetBeans, but that should not make any difference? Checking the actual file hierarchy shows that a package create a subfolder, and within the folder i find the .txt-files I am using. These also shows up under the resources package in project explorer.

Comment: *"Inside these, I have regular .java class files, not jars."*  You mkisunderstood me."*  I suspect your **resources and classes** that are in packages and directories are now **inside a Jar.**  Do you use an IDE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry for late answer. Yes, this is a Java Application. I use Netbeans as my IDE.

Comment: Well, Netbeans will typically package the resources into a Jar before running them.

Comment: Will that make any difference to how i read and write files?

Answer (score 1):

I have busy with other things but have now,  with help from you, found a solution that works on mac and windows.

For some weird reason, `String file = "/" + sourcePackage + "/" + fileNameWithExtension;`is the only thing that works for reading on my mac. Suddenly (no code changes done) it started to work on windows as well. I do not know why. So working code for getting a reader is now:

```
public BufferedReader getFileReader(String fileNameWithExtension, String sourcePackage) {
        try {
            String file = "/" + sourcePackage + "/" + fileNameWithExtension;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
            return br;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For writing to files in the resourses folder, i used:

```
public BufferedWriter getFileWriter(String fileNameWithExtension, String sourcePackage) {
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("src" + File.separator + sourcePackage + File.separator + fileNameWithExtension);
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));            
            return (BufferedWriter) output;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Sadly, not the same way of getting the `Reader`as the `Writer`, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is that *absolute* paths always begin with a '/'. 
Relative paths *must not* begin with a '/'. That's at least part of what's causing problems for you.

For the rest, you say "it doesn't work". But what doesn't work?

Comment: Would you then have a '/' in front of: 'c:/Path/Textfile.txt'? I am using "String file = "/" + sourcePackage + "/" + fileNameWithExtension;" in my code, and this is intended to be a relative path, but i have '/' in front of it and it works. Is this ambiguity, or is it some way removed by parsing?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that works on a Mac. It should certainly work without the '/' and that would also be more portable.